# I want to increase my height (teen girl) with the help of excercise routines and diet

Tags: exercise, diet, workout-routines, growth

I am a 15 year old girl and 5'5 in height.
How can I increase my height in terms of food and exercise? Is there some specific diet plan or routine practice required that could accomplish this?  I would like to be at least 5'7.

Comment: Height is genetically determined. You can't increase it, except with very painful surgery that takes months to recover from (As in immobile recovery), and costs starting at 100,000 (US dollars) and going up. You can go to your doctor and ask for x-rays of the growth plates in your bones to see if you still have growing to do. However, adjusting to whatever height you are mentally is your best option. My wife is 4'9", and she is perfectly happy (As am I).

Comment: If your growth plates haven't closed yet (check after X-Ray), the doctor can put you on expensive growth hormone injections, but these do not come without possible side effects.

Comment: If you have a good diet you can maximize your growth spurts, but you still have a pre determined height you will reach.  I doubt a good diet will even make an inch difference.

Answer (score 13):

You're 15, you still have several years of development left. There's no magical panacea that will suddenly give you a few inches of height, platform shoes or heels not withstanding.

Height is determined by genetics, primarily. However, maintaining a healthy diet, low in processed foods, and keeping yourself fit and active will allow your body to grow to it's fullest potential.

Answer (score 0):

My sister used to be short. She played basketball, volleyball and did a lot of cycling atleast twice a week. She is 5 inches taller than me and it's only been a year.

But, she is 19 now. I think you still have enough time to grow. Just stay active outdoors

Good Luck.